# Node is partially cut off in winform TreeView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, treenode

I am having issues figuring out what this issue is.  I have googled around and have not found many solutions to this issue.  The only "solution" I found was a hack to expand then collapse the last node.

```
this.Nodes[this.Nodes.Count - 1].Expand();
this.Nodes[this.Nodes.Count - 1].Collapse();
```

As you can see from this screen shot the last node is partially cut off and the only way to expose it is to expand the node which will cause the TreeView to re-render itself correctly.

[image]

I am pragmatically adding nodes to the TreeView. I do not know if this affects the outcome, but I have extended the TreeView to my own class so I can add a few properties and methods to it.

```
public class MyTreeView : TreeView
{

public void BuildTree()
{
    this.Nodes.Clear();
    foreach (TestSetFolder folder in Folders)
    {
         MyTreeNode node = new MyTreeNode();
         node.Name = folder.Name;
         node.Text = folder.Name;
         node.Tag = folder;
         node.FolderID = folder.NodeID;
         node.IsPopulated = false;

         this.Nodes.Add(node);
     }
 }
 }
```

This is how I am adding the nodes to the list. Does anyone have a clean solution to this issue?

Comment: Upvoted so you can upload your image..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `treeView.BeginUpdate()`  and `treeView.EndUpdate()` before and after any visual changes.

SuspendLayout() and ResumeLayout() also can be useful!

If you want UI update, do not add all nodes in one go! add one by one, sandwiched between begin and endupdate calls.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. My UI no longer updates while the tree is being built, but the tree now looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `EnsureVisible` on the TreeViewNode in question, like this:

```
treeView1.Nodes[treeView1.Nodes.Count - 1].EnsureVisible();
```

Check the [MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.ensurevisible.aspx) for this method for further information.

**Edit:**
I think I found it. You probably have a root node, and the node you want to scroll into view is a subnode of that root node. Try this instead:

```
        TreeNode rootNode = treeView1.Nodes[0];
        TreeNode lastNode = rootNode.Nodes[rootNode.Nodes.Count - 1];
        lastNode.EnsureVisible();
```

Or use the example from the MSDN article to get the last node:

```
TreeNode lastNode = treeView1.Nodes[treeView1.Nodes.Count - 1].
    Nodes[treeView1.Nodes[treeView1.Nodes.Count - 1].Nodes.Count - 1];
```

Comment: I do not have a root node, sorry.

Comment: Well, in my own example it works, the last node scrolls into view. I can see no reason why it should not work for you...

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Expand method in the TreeNode class.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.aspx

Comment: In my original question, I stated that I had used the expand, followed by collapse, which solves my issues. This is not the solution I am looking for. I am wondering why the item is cut-off in the first place.  The reason I don't want to do the expand, collapse is because on an expand, it queries an API for the content inside that node. I do it this way to save initial load time, otherwise the load would take forever